# get user permissions using user_id postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this database i have users , roles , user_roles , roles_permissions
user can have multiple role also role can have multiple permission so to get all user permissions
i wrote this query select first all user roles then select permissions for every role and then filter it with user_id

```
SELECT p.permission_id , p.permission_name 
FROM permissions p 
JOIN role_permissions rp ON p.permission_id = rp.permission_id 
JOIN roles r ON r.role_id = rp.role_id 
JOIN user_roles ur ON r.role_id = ur.role_id 
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ur.user_id 
WHERE u.user_id = 1
```

is there a better way to do this without changing database design?

[image]

I want to optimize my sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me, only optimization you can make is to skip join on table "roles" altogether - role_id is same for user_roles, roles and role_permissions

```
SELECT p.permission_id , p.permission_name 
FROM permissions p 
JOIN role_permissions rp ON p.permission_id = rp.permission_id 
JOIN user_roles ur ON rp.role_id = ur.role_id 
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ur.user_id 
WHERE u.user_id = 1
```